# Mongoose aggregate returns pipeline query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

So I'm having a bit of trouble here with this part of my backend.

When I try to filter my document, it returns the pipeline.

Here's the code and the output.

I'm pretty sure I'm doing something wrong, but I can't see it and I've spent around 2 hours trying different aggregate methods but none of them works.

If I use the same aggregate code on the MongoDB Compass software, it returns what it is supposed to return.

Hope someone can help me and thank you for your time.

#### Mongoose model

```js
const AccesoClientes = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    cliente: { type: String, required: true },
    servidorCliente: { type: String, default: "" },
    credenciales: { type: String, default: "" },
    servidorSql: { type: String, default: "" },
    servidorServicios: { type: String, default: "" },
    programas: { type: Array, default: ["Sige"] },
    tipo: {type: String, default: ""},
    notas: { type: String, default: "" },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);
```

#### Express call

```js
router.get("/todos", async (req, res) => {
  const type = req.query.filter;
  let registro;
  try {
    if (!type) {
      registro = await AccesoClientes.find();
    } else {
      pipeline = [{$match: {tipo: type}}]
      registro = AccesoClientes.aggregate(pipeline, {allowDiskUse: true});
      console.log(type);
    }
    res.status(201).json(registro);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(501).json(err);
  }
});
```

#### Output

```json
{
    "_pipeline": [
        {
            "$match": {
                "tipo": "interno"
            }
        }
    ],
    "options": {
        "allowDiskUse": true
    }
}
```

#### Expected output

```json
{
        "_id": "625847c2fcd6a676fc85b19f",
        "cliente": "Alpex",
        "servidorCliente": "172.27.100.14",
        "credenciales": "CLOUD",
        "servidorSql": "172.27.100.12",
        "servidorServicios": "172.27.100.17",
        "programas": [
            [
                "Pool",
                "Sige"
            ]
        ],
        "notas": "",
        "createdAt": "2022-04-14T16:11:46.899Z",
        "updatedAt": "2022-04-14T16:11:46.899Z",
        "__v": 0,
        "tipo": "interno"
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to execute the `aggregate`. Right now you are just defining it but not executing it.

Try this

```
registro = await AccesoClientes.aggregate(pipeline, {allowDiskUse: true});
```

This is similar to how you are doing `await AccesoClientes.find()`

Comment: Thank you so much I never thought it could be that easy fix.